# How to Find Password/ Bypass Password in a Switch Statement using IDA

Tags: ida, windows, binary-analysis, binary-format

I'm new to reverse engineering, wondering how access or bypass the password contained in the switch statement ?
[image: The Generate Pseudocode in IDA]

[**File Link**](https://github.com/leon7731/Reverse-Engineering-Find-Password)

Comment: You should really give more details. How is the password provided? The shown method has two parameters but none of them is ever used. When asking a question it is better to include all relevant data instead of just linking to an external file.

Comment: Please post code as text instead of an image. Makes it easier for others to read/copy and for sites like google to index.

Comment: Also it depends on a lot of factors here. Just by looking at this switch I can say its sort of a VM that has been implemented and we might need the whole binary to analyze this.

Comment: @Robert they are used in case 5 and they are argc and argv[1]  it takes an argument from command line

Comment: @blabb Correct. I did not notice because the code was added as screenshot so it could not be searched for text (-> Leon please do not add code as screenshot. Always copy the text!)